# Face error with XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, web-services

I am working on a Java web base project, where I am using web service to access date and update the date, my screen has a date field, which I need to update with the data acquired form the web service, but the web service date is of type `XMLGregorianCalendar`.

This is what I have:

```
public class Testing {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {


    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = (Date)df.parse("5-5-2012");
        System.out.println("Date Date" + date);
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    GregorianCalendar gregory = new GregorianCalendar();
    gregory.setTime(date);
     System.out.println(""+gregory);

     XMLGregorianCalendar calendar =null;
    try {
        calendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregory);
    } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    calendar.setTimezone( DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED );
    someDoa.setdate(calendar);

}

}
```

But the result is:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incorrect Offset :Incorrect Offset :needs a leading +/- sign
```

Comment: On which line does your program throw this exception? This code doesn't seem to access anz kind of webservice whatsoever... Your error seems to be a data format mismatch between the server and the client...

Comment: at last line  someDoa.setdate(calendar);

Comment: Why are you just printing stack traces and then continuing if there's an exception? You don't have valid data at that point...

Comment: Sounds like this exception is not interleaved with your test.

Comment: What is the type of `someDoa`? You haven't declared it anywhere. (It's also somewhat odd that you're talking about a servlet failing, but you've just presented a `main` method...)

Comment: someDoa is getter ans setter class with  protected XMLGregorianCalendar productionDatePostGirot;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)